# Replace value in a pandas dataframe column by the previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, outliers

My code detects outliers in a time series. Which I want to do is to replace the outliers in de first dataframe column with the previous value which is not an outlier.

This code just detect outliers, creating a boolean array where:

- `True` means that a value in the dataframe is an outlier
- `False` means that a value in the dataframe is not an outlier

> ```
> series = read_csv('horario_completo.csv', header=None,  squeeze=True)
> df=pd.DataFrame(series)
> from pandas import rolling_median
>
> consumos=df.iloc[:,0]
> df['rolling_median'] = rolling_median(consumos, window=48, center=True).fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
> threshold =50
> difference = np.abs(consumos - df['rolling_median'])
> outlier = difference > threshold
> ```

Up to this point, everything works.

The next step I have thought is to create a mask to replace the `True`values with the previous value of the same column (if this was possible, it would be much faster than making a loop).

I'll try to explain it with a little example:

This is what I have:

```
index consumo

  0      54
  1      67
  2      98


index outlier 

  0    False
  1    False
  2    True
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
index consumo

  0     54
  1     67
  2     67
```

I think I should create a mask like this:

```
df.mask(outlier, df.columns=[[0]][i-1],axis=1)
```

obviosly this IS NOT the way to write it. It just an explanation about how I think it could be done (I'm talking about the [i-1]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
consumo = consumo.mask(outlier, consumo.shift())
print (consumo)
0    54.0
1    67.0
2    67.0
Name: consumo, dtype: float64
```

Last if all values are `ints` add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
consumo = consumo.mask(outlier, consumo.shift()).astype(int)
print (consumo)
0    54
1    67
2    67
Name: consumo, dtype: int32
```

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of shift(). It is really really useful. And your answer is clear and works really well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad can  help, nice day!